# How to use long-polling for pushing server side events?

Tags: jakarta-ee, long-polling

I know the basics stuff: how the mechanism works, its limits, etc. However, I want to utilize long-polling to allow other developers in my team to push events to the client (in my case, the browser) when convenient.

I am working with Java EE, where I can use `AsyncServlet`. I was thinking of creating a server side api (Java) as well as a client side (Javascript) to hide the implementation details under a nice abstraction.

My initial idea was to create an api which is similar to that exposed by JMS and other Message Oriented Middlewares (like apache Artemis or Rabbitmq). What do you think? Is there any library that offers a high level api for long-polling (for Java EE)?

Comment: I've used [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) for this as it's cross platform / language.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks, but I'm looking to build my own or through a library since I cannot use an external service.

Comment: Ok - never used it but [CometD](https://cometd.org/) is something I've researched in the past.

Comment: Thanks, but whenever it comes to CometD, the answer is a nice no thank you :) . I also have looked into it and came to the conclusion that is overengineered and too complicated to comprehend and use.